# "Unable to create process ...\project1.exe" when debugging a Win64 apps in Windows 8

Tags: windows, delphi, debugging

I am using Delphi XE4 Update 1.  When I build and run a simple VCL application compiled with Win64 platform on Windows 8.  I encountered an error:

```
"Unable to create process: ...\project1.exe"
```

However, it works if I run the `project1.exe` without debugging.

I have tried to figure out what happens but failed to rectify the problem.

I have tried these:

1. Uninstall and reinstall XE4
2. I run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\11.0\bin\dbkw64_18_0.exe` and it flash a while and close without any errors.  Other Window 8 machine will run the program and stay in the desktop.
3. I reset Window 8 Firewall rules.  When I run the app in debugger, it didn't prompt me the usual firewall rules dialog.
4. I add a Firewall rules for `dbkw64_18_0.exe` and but it doesn't work
5. When I attempt to debug the app with Win64 platform, a new process `rmtdbg180.exe` is created.  Each attempt to start the app in debugger will create a new `rmtdbg180.exe` process.  This doesn't happen on other Windows 8 machine.

Anyone has ideas what happen to my machine?

Comment: There were problems with XE2 and XE3 for debugging 64 bit projects on Win8. But I think they were all fixed in XE4.

Comment: Can it be problem of user right or privileges ? You can try to include your account into local Administrators group and assign local policy "Debug programs" (normally it is not required, but maybe there some changes in W8)?

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn: The file `dbkw64_18_0.exe` is installed default location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\11.0\bin`.  It has local Administrators group as well.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have a Win8 virtual machine installed the Delphi XE4.  The Win64 apps can run in Delphi IDE debugger without problem.  I wonder if there are other settings that cause the problem.  I did install `AQTime` before on my machine but I have uninstalled it.

Comment: I install a fresh Windows 8.1 and problem gone.  The problems remain unknown.

Comment: I've seen this message with XE6 a couple of times; Clean & Build solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

May be you checked "Run this program as an Administrator" in Executable File Properties menu Compatibility tab.
Uncheck this

Answer (score 1):

You probably blocked bds.exe in your firewall. To debug 64bit application you must allow bds.exe to connect to the internet, or at least to local network.

Comment: turning off the firewall does not help, I don't think that it's a firewall issue

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered this issue with Berlin and was able to resolve it by going to the Bin64 folder and resetting the security settings through the advanced settings.

Comment: could you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1):

Save and close Delphi then restart it with Run As Administrator. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin` folder and find `bds.exe` than click on right button and select run as administrator. It works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Get full access in the security tab for the current user to the path where the project files are located. For instance, set the necessary privileges for the top directory and then inherit them for all deeper paths.  There is no need to run RAD with administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

RSP-29884

The debugger fails to connect to the port 64448 because the port is in the excluded ports list. To check the list execute:

`netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

To flush this list stop and restart the winnat service.
Run as Admin: `net stop winnat` and `net start winnat`
Now recheck the list with netsh.
Debug works again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, following RSP-29884 comments, the problem has been solved running the following command line.

`netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=64448 numberofports=1`