# Delphi: Unable to create process

Tags: delphi, debugging, windows-11

I've got exactly this problem: ["Unable to create process ...\project1.exe" when debugging a Win64 apps in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268908/unable-to-create-process-project1-exe-when-debugging-a-win64-apps-in-windo)

But none of the answers then solves the problem. On the 10th and 11th I had updates from Microsoft for Windows 11. It can hardly not have anything to do with that. Anyone else experiencing this problem?

```
Windows 11 Pro v10.0.22000 build 22000
KB4023057, KB85011493, KB5012417, KB5012418, KB5012416 installed recently
Delphi 10.4 Version 27.0.40680.4203
```

[image]

Comment: Never mind. I rebooted Windows 11 and now it's working again. Weird.

Comment: Look at Windows Event Viewer...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i just run BDS as administrator

Comment: I tried that, never works for me. Only a reboot will solve it. Nasty problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32840078)